# IQueryable - Why does this logic fail?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a data base with several tables, the pertinent ones in this case are

VolunteerSignups and ProgramEvents:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VolunteerSignups] (
    [EventId]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [VolunteerNum] INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserId]       NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.VolunteerSignups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EventId] ASC, [VolunteerNum] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_VolunteerSignups_ProgramEvents_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_VolunteerSignups_ProgramEvents_EventId] FOREIGN KEY ([EventId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ProgramEvents] ([EventId])
);
--Triggers and other unneeded info

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProgramEvents] (
    [EventId]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [EventTitle]         NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [NumVolunteers]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [EventLocation]      NVARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
    [ServiceDescription] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [StartTime]          DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [EndTime]            DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ProgramEvents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EventId] ASC)
);
--Triggers and other unneeded info
```

What I have, overall, is a simple web app that allows events to be made (each event may have anywhere from 1 to N volunteers needed), and volunteers to sign up for said events.  The restriction is, of course, that the volunteers cannot sign up for the same event twice and that they cannot sign up for overlapping ( time-wise) slots.

I have quite literally everything else in the MVC app done except the second half of the volunteer slot requirement. I struggled with it some, got annoyed, so I left it for last instead of letting it delay the project overall.  But now I can't put it off anymore, because everything else works but this one query....

What I have so far is:

```
[Authorize( Roles = "Administrator, Volunteer" )]
public class VolunteerSignupsController : Controller
{
    private EntitiesDb db = new EntitiesDb();

    // GET: VolunteerSignups
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var uid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var exclude = ( db.VolunteerSignups.Where( o => o.UserId == uid ) );

        var volunteerSignups = db.VolunteerSignups.Include( v => v.AspNetUser ).Include( v => v.ProgramEvent );
        var diff = volunteerSignups.Where( u => ( !exclude.Any( p => p.EventId == u.EventId ) ) && u.UserId == null );

        return View( await diff.ToListAsync() );
    }
```

This code work perfectly at retrieving the events that the user has not signed up for already.  The problem is that it returns overlapping events after they have signed up for an event.  So I modified the code to the following:

```
[Authorize( Roles = "Administrator, Volunteer" )]
public class VolunteerSignupsController : Controller
{
    private EntitiesDb db = new EntitiesDb();

    // GET: VolunteerSignups
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db1 = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var uid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var exclude = ( db.VolunteerSignups.Where( o => o.UserId == uid ) );

        var volunteerSignups = db.VolunteerSignups.Include( v => v.AspNetUser ).Include( v => v.ProgramEvent );
        var diff = volunteerSignups.Where( u => ( !exclude.Any( p => p.EventId == u.EventId ) ) && u.UserId == null );

        //GET: ProgramEvents that user has already signed up for
        var alreadyVolunteeredFor = db.ProgramEvents.Where( i => exclude.Any( u => i.EventId == u.EventId ) );

        //GET: ProgramEvents that the user has not signed up for 
        var qualifiesFor = db.ProgramEvents.Where( i => diff.Any( u => i.EventId == u.EventId ) );

        /*Get: VolunteerSignups where the ProgramEvent is one where:
               -The user has not previously volunteered
               -The user has not previously volunteered for a different event where the time overlaps with an event they have not signed up for*/
        var intersect = db.VolunteerSignups.Where( i => ( diff.Any( d => ( d.EventId == i.EventId ) &&
            !qualifiesFor.Any( q => q.EventId == i.EventId &&
             alreadyVolunteeredFor.Any( a => a.EventId == i.EventId &&
               a.EndTime.CompareTo( q.StartTime ) >= 0  &&
               a.StartTime.CompareTo( q.EndTime ) <= 0  ) ) ) ) );

        return View( await intersect.ToListAsync() );
    }
```

I am pretty sure the logic failure lies in the lambda expressions that make up `intersect`.  As it is written, it just returns the exact same things that `diff` did prior. Any changes I make to it, though, seem to remove everything from that list.

EDIT to respond to [mjwillis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) comment:

The data in `diff` will be `VolunteerSignups` rows that are not filled for an event that the user has not volunteered for.  The columns are
 1.`xyz 1 null`

2.`xyz 2 null`

3.`abc 1 null`

`qualifiesFor` should correspond to `ProgramEvents` rows that have the same `EventId` as the entries in `diff`:
 1.`xyz "First Title" 2 "Some Location" "A Description" "11/1/2020 4:00pm" "11/1/2020 7:00pm"`
 2. `abc "Second Title" 1 "A Location" "Some Description" "11/1/2020 5:00pm" "11/1/2020 6:00pm"`

`alreadyVonteeredFor` should correspond to `ProgramEvents` rows person has volunteered for, none of the `EventId` columns should equal eachother, nor should they be if either `diff` or `qualifiesFor`:

1. `dsd "Already Volunteered" 1 "Some Place" "Time overlaps" "11/1/2020 3:00pm" "11/1/2020 4:30pm"`

What I need is for `intersect` to contain `diff` row 3 only, because rows 1 and 2 correspond to an event who's time overlaps with an event that the volunteer is already attached to.

Comment: `The problem is that it returns overlapping events after they have signed up for an event` Please update your post to show some sample input data, the data that is **currently** being returned and the data you **want instead** to be returned...

Comment: I added an edit.  The TLDR of it is that I need time slots to not overlap.  You can't be in two places at once, the volunteer signup data is in one table and the time data is in another, linked by a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.  The issue was with the `a => a.EventId == i.EventId &&` in the `intersect` lambda.  That is nonsense, and I don't know why it would be in there.  Nothing in `alreadyVolunteeredFor` would be in `qualifiesFor` and none of the `EventId` column would be in it either.

The correct answer ended up being to change the declaration of `intersect` to:

```
var intersect = db.VolunteerSignups.Where( i => ( diff.Any( d => ( d.EventId == i.EventId ) &&
            qualifiesFor.Any( q => q.EventId == i.EventId &&
             !alreadyVolunteeredFor.Any( a =>
               (a.EndTime.CompareTo( q.StartTime ) >= 0)  &&
               (a.StartTime.CompareTo( q.EndTime ) <= 0 ) ) ) ) ) );
```